# Vaadin - Micronaut integration

Tags: java, vaadin, micronaut

I am selecting a new technology for my team. I would like to use Vaadin in some situations but I would like to reduce the number of technologies that my team needs to assimilate. Is it technically possible to use [Micronaut](https://micronaut.io/index.html) security and Inversion of Control in [Vaadin Flow](https://vaadin.com/flow)?

Comment: Afaik Vaadin relies on the Servlet API. The Micronaut web server is not a servlet so it would likely require lots of work to bridge the APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would deploy Micronaut a set of Microservices that expose REST APIs, you would then integrate these REST APIs into your UI application which would run as a separate instance.

See https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/microservices/consuming-stateless-services

For a tutorial which uses Spring as the backend Microservice but you could swap that out for Micronaut or Node or whichever backend technology and maintain a separate application for the Vaadin UI

Answer (score 2):

While I do not know Micronaut, [its documentation](https://micronaut.io/faq.html) says it is aimed squarely at [microservices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices).

That would be orthogonal to using [Vaadin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin) Flow. Vaadin is aimed at creating the user-interface for web apps. With Vaadin, the programmer defines a form with labels, fields, and buttons and other widgets all in Java. This pure Java runs on the sever-side in a Java Servlets container. Vaadin automatically generates the necessary HTML, CSS, JavaScript, DOM, AJAX, WebSocket, and Push code to render the Java-defined UI remotely in the user’s web browser. So a Vaadin app, depending on the content and number of users, may make use of many cores and much memory on the server.

In contrast Microservices are narrowly focused to perform a limited simple job of processing: data-in and data-out. Often with low memory-footprint. No user-interface involved.

So while the Java code of a Vaadin app might call upon a Microservice, for example to look up a tax rate for calculating an invoice, there is no overlap here. Vaadin and Microservices fulfill separate purposes.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am interested in something similar to the integration between Vaading and Spring Boot but with Micronaut.